# What is the lifetime of shared memory on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-memory

I am creating, writing to and reading from a shared segment on Linux using the ftok/shmget/shmat/shmdt functions.

If I write to the segment in one program which then exits, and subsequently read the segment from another program later, I am surprised to find the data still there.

I would have expected that when the last process sharing a segment does a shmdt, the segment would be free'd.

Can I rely on this behavior? Or is it analogous to continuing to use a pointer after free()'ing it?

Comment: Freeing the segment and replacing the data are two different thing. Freeing doesn't necessarily means the old data has been replaced. Until the segment is over-written by some other process it will have the data it initially had but to other programs it is garbage.

Comment: Detaching (shmdt) does not destroy a shared memory segment.  To do so you will need to do a shmctl() specifying IPC_RMID as "cmd".  But note the man page (on Linux) indicates that the shared memory segment ID will not be destroyed until all processes have detached (shmdt) from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shared memory area remains until it is deleted via `shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,...)` [or system reboot]. This will take effect after every process has done `shmdt` [or terminated].

The semantics are very similar to a file. `shmat` is like `open`. `shmdt` is like `close` and the [above] `shmctl` is like `unlink`.

If you close a file, you'd like it to persist until specifically deleted, wouldn't you? So, shared memory segments operate similarly

Answer (score 0):

`shmdt` only detaches you memory, no erase/overwrite is performed on the data segment. Until some other process maps and uses it again data will persevere.

Also, you should use newer, POSIX compliant `mmap`.

Comment: Shared memory segments have at least kernel lifetime, and in general they disappeared at reboot. That means that you have to remove them explicitly (IPC_RMID operation of semctl). You can think of them as *temporary files*.