# Relationship between shared memory and files

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory

Ignoring some details there are two low-level SHM APIs available for in Linux.

We have the *older* (e.g [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc)) SysV interface using:

- ftok
- shmctl
- shmget
- shmat
- shmdt

and the *newer* Posix interface (though Posix seems to standardize the SysV one as well):

- shm_open
- shm_unlink

When using shm_open() there appears to be a clear 1 to 1 mapping between files and shared memory segments.
However if you use shmget() you can relate multiple segments to a single path using, for example:

```
key1=ftok(path,1);
key2=ftok(path,2);
shmget(key1,...)
shmget(key2,...)
```

**What if anything the relationship between files and segments in this case?
The path given to ftok is just a placeholder. I can't see what purpose it serves.
If we consider the Unix philosophy as everything is a file why is this not a one to one mapping?**

Separate but related question:

- Should the SysV interface be considered deprecated?

There is no such suggestion in [shm_open](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) or [shm_get](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html)

I can find only vague suggestions like:

- https://www.unix.com/linux/53491-shmat-failure-while-using-large-amount-shared-memory.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35666695/1569204

I think the SysV is considered less thread-safe.

Is there any reason why you might prefer the SysV one (or the posix one) in a modern application?

Comment: Related to this I am suspicious that shmget() is actually returning the same memory segment as I am currently investigating a bug where it appears that data written to the segment returned by key2 appears in the segment returned by key1. I haven't yet ruled out this being a bug on my part though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path given to ftok is just a placeholder in the "everything is a file" tradition.

After some time considering I would say mmap is a simpler, safer and more effective API. I personally would avoid shmget etc. completely if possible.

It is particularly awkward to clean up after shmget() see:

- [Linux IPC: shared memory recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408450/linux-ipc-shared-memory-recovery/68408451#68408451)

See also:

- [Linux shared memory: shmget() vs mmap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311080/linux-shared-memory-shmget-vs-mmap)
- [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc)
- [How do you correctly cleanup and re-use SysV shared memory segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66875715/how-do-you-correctly-cleanup-and-re-use-sysv-shared-memory-segments)

An argument used in favour of system-v in one of the linked questions is that Posix was less widely implemented. I don't know if that was true then but it seems even less likely to be true now. Given the dominance of GNU/Linux & BSD derivatives. Even the legendarily 'unique' AIX claims Posix compliance these days.