# Is it possible to share memory using the SysV shmat() interface in one application and the Posix shm_open() interace in another?

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory

Ignoring some details there are two low-level SHM APIs available for in Linux.

We have the *older* (e.g [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc)) SysV interface using:

- ftok
- shmctl
- shmget
- shmat
- shmdt

and the *newer* Posix interface (though Posix seems to standardize the SysV one as well):

- shm_open
- shm_unlink

It is possible and safe to share memory such that one program uses shm_open() while the other uses shmget() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is no, though someone wiser may know better.

*shm_open(path,...)* maps **one** file to a shared memory segment whereas *ftok(path,id,...)* maps a named placeholder file to **one or more** segments.
See this related question - [Relationship between shared memory and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859573/relationship-between-shared-memory-and-files)

So on the one hand you have a one to one mapping between filenames and segments and on the other a one to many - as in the linked question.

Also the path used by *shmget()* is just a placeholder. For shm_open() the map might be the actual file (though this is implementation defined).

I'm not sure there is anyway to make shm_open() and shmat() refer to the same memory location.
Even if you could mix them somehow it would probably be undefined behaviour.

If you look the glibc implementation of [shm_open](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c.html#shm_open) it is simply a wrapper to opening a file.
The implementation of [shmget](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shmget.c.html) and [shmat](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shmat.c.html#shmat) are internal system calls.

It may be that they share an implementation further down in the Linux kernal but this is not a detail that should be exposed or relied upon.